# What is wrong with my query on Access 2010?

Tags: ms-access

I have this query on Access 2010 (accdb) which is working perfectly fine:

```
SELECT b.category_name, a.item_name,  
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_stock_receiving AS x WHERE x.safe_stock_id = a.ID) AS received,   
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_stock_issuance AS y WHERE y.stock_receiving_id = a.ID) AS issued,
(received-issued) AS on_hand, a.safe_stock  
FROM tbl_safe_stock AS a INNER JOIN tbl_category AS b
ON a.category_id = b.id
ORDER BY a.item_name;
```

Now, I need to modify it to include a simple WHERE statement

```
...
ON a.category_id = b.id
WHERE a.safe_stock > on_hand
ORDER BY a.item_name;
...
```

When I run the query, Access keeps popping up for a parameter value for

> on_hand

on_hand is an Alias as you can see on

```
(received-issued) AS on_hand
```

What could be wrong in my query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've defined `on_hand` as the name of an *output* column, but the SQL parser isn't clever enough to go back through your query and "reverse engineer" where `on_hand` came from. Therefore, you'd need to use something like `WHERE a.safe_stock > (received - issued)`, but they are aliases for output columns, too.

So try wrapping the whole thing up as a subquery and then applying the `WHERE` and `ORDER BY` clauses afterward:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT b.category_name, a.item_name,  
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_stock_receiving AS x WHERE x.safe_stock_id = a.ID) AS received,   
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_stock_issuance AS y WHERE y.stock_receiving_id = a.ID) AS issued,
    (received-issued) AS on_hand, a.safe_stock  
    FROM tbl_safe_stock AS a INNER JOIN tbl_category AS b
    ON a.category_id = b.id
)
WHERE safe_stock > on_hand
ORDER BY item_name
```

### Edit

The suggestion above resulted in a "Query is too complex" error, so my next suggestion was to save the original query as [StockCheckBaseQuery] and then do

```
SELECT * FROM StockCheckBaseQuery WHERE safe_stock > on_hand ORDER BY item_name
```

That appears to have been successful.

Comment: ok, I have replace 'on_hand' with '(received - issued)'  
Now it asking for parameter values for 'received' and possibly for 'issued' also.

How do I make those field fully-qualified?

Comment: @Ruben Sorry, I should have noticed that `received` and `issued` were output aliases, too. I have updated my answer. Please let me know if that works.

Comment: I appreciate your help, when running your query, it says 'Query is too complex.'. Any ideas?

Comment: @Ruben Hmm, okay, try saving your original query as [StockCheckBaseQuery] and then doing `SELECT * FROM StockCheckBaseQuery WHERE safe_stock > on_hand ORDER BY item_name`